# Display groups a user belongs to by searching their email address - Quest Powershell Active Roles Management Shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is the command I'm using currently:

> $user = Get-QADUser -email user@domain.com -enabled ; $user.memberOf |
>   Get-QADGroup | findstr Green

"Green" is just an identifying marker on group names.

Sometimes this command works just fine. It displays to me, based on the email address input, all groups that match "Green" that the user belongs to.

Sometimes, however, it does not... and I get this:

> Get-QADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
>   argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that  is not null or
>   empty and then try the command again. At line:1 char:97
>   + $user = Get-QADUser -email user@domain.com -enabled ; $user.memberOf | Get-QADGroup <<<<  | findstr Green
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-QADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlet
>   s.GetGroupCmdlet

I've been googling and trying modifications of and variations on this for weeks on and off, and no luck. I'm hoping someone can explain the inconsistent behavior and provide a better or just more consistently working command.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Get-QADMemberOf -Identity user@domain.com -Name Green
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Get-QADUser -Email user@domain.com -Enabled | Get-QADMemberOf -Name green ?

Comment: I get this error:

Get-QADMemberOf : Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'user@domain.com'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Get-QADMemberOf <<<<  -Identity user@domain.com -Name Green
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-QADMemberOf], ObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.DirectoryAccess.ObjectNotFoundException,Quest.Acti
   veRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.GetMemberOfCmdlet

Also I can't get the formatting to not scrunch up... apologies for that, if there's a way to fix that let me know.

Comment: ah you saw my thing before I deleted to repost to try to fix the formatting, let me try your new suggestion and I'll let you know

Comment: Ok, Get-QADUser -Email user@domain.com -Enabled | Get-QADMemberOf -Name green  --  This works, sorta. It doesn't return an error, but it gives no output.

Comment: Try to use wildcards if 'green' is only a part of the group name (e.g *green*)

Comment: Users on the NA (north america) domain appear to work fine. (As far as my limited understanding can tell) but users in EMEA (europe, middle east, asia) aren't returning results. I'm in NA, so maybe that's why NA is working and EMEA is not? Is there a way to tell it to check other/all domains?

Comment: You'll need to create a connection to each domain, use the Connect-QADService cmdlet

Comment: I'll look into that, and post back once I've had a chance to play around with that and test it out a bit, thanks much.